# How to abs() the ticks on the density axis of a violin plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, axis

I wrote a function to plot density violins comparing the values of two seperate data frames. One is represented in the upper half of the violin, the other one in the lower half.
I achieved this by simply writing the densities of the lower half -y (See line 36).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcuAv.jpg

Since densities can only be positive, I'd like to use positive ticks on the density axis. What's the simplest way to keep the ticks just where they are but label them abs()?

---

EDIT: just to make it crystal clear, what I'm trying to get ;)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1GuW.jpg

---

```
require(ggplot2)
require(dplyr)

interpolate <- function(x.left, x.right, y.left, y.right, x.fill){
  y.fill <- (y.right - y.left) / (x.right - x.left) * (x.fill - x.left) + y.left
  return(y.fill)
}

add.quantiles.to.density <- function(plotline, quantiles){
  for (i in 1:length(quantiles)){
    x.fill <- as.numeric(quantiles)[i]
    pre    <- plotline %>% filter(x <= x.fill)
    post   <- plotline %>% filter(x >= x.fill)
    x.1    <- pre[nrow(pre), "x"]
    x.2    <- post[1, "x"]
    y.1    <- pre[nrow(pre), "y"]
    y.2    <- post[1, "y"]
    y.fill <- interpolate(x.1, x.2, y.1, y.2, x.fill)
    plotline <- rbind(pre, c(x.fill, y.fill, as.numeric(as.character(pre[nrow(pre), "quant"]))), c(x.fill, y.fill, as.numeric(as.character(post[1, "quant"]))), post)
  }
  return(plotline)
}

plot.violin.density.comparison <- function(colname, upper, lower, quantiles){
  upper.col <- select(upper, c(colname))
  lower.col <- select(lower, c(colname))
  colnames(upper.col)<- "values"
  colnames(lower.col)<- "values"
  density.data.u <- density(upper.col$values,
                            bw = min(abs(max(upper.col$values)-min(upper.col$values)),
                                     abs(max(lower.col$values)-min(lower.col$values))) / 128)
  density.data.l <- density(lower.col$values,
                            bw = min(abs(max(upper.col$values)-min(upper.col$values)),
                                     abs(max(lower.col$values)-min(lower.col$values))) / 128)
  plotline.u     <- data.frame(x = density.data.u$x, y =  density.data.u$y)
  plotline.l     <- data.frame(x = density.data.l$x, y = -density.data.l$y)
  quantiles.u    <- quantile(upper.col$values, quantiles)
  quantiles.l    <- quantile(lower.col$values, quantiles)
  plotline.u$quant <- factor(findInterval(plotline.u$x, quantiles.u))
  plotline.l$quant <- as.factor(as.numeric(factor(findInterval(plotline.l$x, quantiles.l))) + length(quantiles) + 1)
  plotline.u <- add.quantiles.to.density(plotline.u, quantiles.u)
  plotline.l <- add.quantiles.to.density(plotline.l, quantiles.l)
  plotline    <- rbind(plotline.l, plotline.u)

  ggplot(plotline, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = y, fill = quant)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "#FFC090", "#FF6030", "#FF3000", "#FF0030", "#FF3060", "#FF90C0", "white",
                                 "white", "#C090FF", "#6030FF", "#3000FF", "#0030FF", "#3060FF", "#90C0FF", "white"),
                      guide = "none") +
    scale_x_continuous(name = paste("value of", colname),
                       limits = c( min(plotline$x),      max(plotline$x))) +
    scale_y_continuous(name = paste("density of ", colname, "\'s values", sep=""),
                       limits = c(-max(abs(plotline$y)), max(abs(plotline$y)))) +
    geom_segment(aes(x    = mean(upper.col$values),
                     xend = mean(upper.col$values),
                     y    = 0,
                     yend = plotline.u[which.min(abs(plotline.u$x-mean(upper.col$values))), "y"])) +
    geom_segment(aes(x    = mean(lower.col$values),
                     xend = mean(lower.col$values),
                     y    = 0,
                     yend = plotline.l[which.min(abs(plotline.l$x-mean(lower.col$values))), "y"]))
}

colname <- "blah"
upper   <- data.frame(x = c(1:1024), y = runif(1024, min = -1, max = 1), blah = runif(1024, min = -0.5, max = 0.5))
lower   <- data.frame(x = c(1:2048), y = runif(2048, min = -3, max = 3), blah = runif(2048, min = -0.3, max = 0.6))
quantiles <- c(0.01, 0.05, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95, 0.99)
plot.violin.density.comparison(colname, upper, lower, quantiles)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
scale_y_continuous can use a function as the `labels` argument. So I only needed to add add

> `labels = function(x) abs(x)`

as an argument and it works just the way I wanted.
If you want to try it yourself, here's the code:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(dplyr)

interpolate <- function(x.left, x.right, y.left, y.right, x.fill){
  y.fill <- (y.right - y.left) / (x.right - x.left) * (x.fill - x.left) + y.left
  return(y.fill)
}

add.quantiles.to.density <- function(plotline, quantiles){
  for (i in 1:length(quantiles)){
    x.fill <- as.numeric(quantiles)[i]
    pre    <- plotline %>% filter(x <= x.fill)
    post   <- plotline %>% filter(x >= x.fill)
    x.1    <- pre[nrow(pre), "x"]
    x.2    <- post[1, "x"]
    y.1    <- pre[nrow(pre), "y"]
    y.2    <- post[1, "y"]
    y.fill <- interpolate(x.1, x.2, y.1, y.2, x.fill)
    plotline <- rbind(pre, c(x.fill, y.fill, as.numeric(as.character(pre[nrow(pre), "quant"]))), c(x.fill, y.fill, as.numeric(as.character(post[1, "quant"]))), post)
  }
  return(plotline)
}

plot.violin.density.comparison <- function(colname, upper, lower, quantiles){
  upper.col <- select(upper, c(colname))
  lower.col <- select(lower, c(colname))
  colnames(upper.col)<- "values"
  colnames(lower.col)<- "values"
  density.data.u <- density(upper.col$values,
                            bw = min(abs(max(upper.col$values)-min(upper.col$values)),
                                     abs(max(lower.col$values)-min(lower.col$values))) / 128)
  density.data.l <- density(lower.col$values,
                            bw = min(abs(max(upper.col$values)-min(upper.col$values)),
                                     abs(max(lower.col$values)-min(lower.col$values))) / 128)
  plotline.u     <- data.frame(x = density.data.u$x, y =  density.data.u$y)
  plotline.l     <- data.frame(x = density.data.l$x, y = -density.data.l$y)
  quantiles.u    <- quantile(upper.col$values, quantiles)
  quantiles.l    <- quantile(lower.col$values, quantiles)
  plotline.u$quant <- factor(findInterval(plotline.u$x, quantiles.u))
  plotline.l$quant <- as.factor(as.numeric(factor(findInterval(plotline.l$x, quantiles.l))) + length(quantiles) + 1)
  plotline.u <- add.quantiles.to.density(plotline.u, quantiles.u)
  plotline.l <- add.quantiles.to.density(plotline.l, quantiles.l)
  plotline    <- rbind(plotline.l, plotline.u)

  ggplot(plotline, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = y, fill = quant)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "#FFC090", "#FF6030", "#FF3000", "#FF0030", "#FF3060", "#FF90C0", "white",
                                 "white", "#C090FF", "#6030FF", "#3000FF", "#0030FF", "#3060FF", "#90C0FF", "white"),
                      guide = "none") +
    scale_x_continuous(name = paste("value of", colname),
                       limits = c( min(plotline$x),      max(plotline$x))) +
    scale_y_continuous(name = paste("density of ", colname, "\'s values", sep=""),
                       limits = c(-max(abs(plotline$y)), max(abs(plotline$y))),
                       labels = function(x) abs(x)) +
    geom_segment(aes(x    = mean(upper.col$values),
                     xend = mean(upper.col$values),
                     y    = 0,
                     yend = plotline.u[which.min(abs(plotline.u$x-mean(upper.col$values))), "y"])) +
    geom_segment(aes(x    = mean(lower.col$values),
                     xend = mean(lower.col$values),
                     y    = 0,
                     yend = plotline.l[which.min(abs(plotline.l$x-mean(lower.col$values))), "y"]))
}

colname <- "blah"
upper   <- data.frame(x = c(1:1024), y = runif(1024, min = -1, max = 1), blah = runif(1024, min = -0.5, max = 0.5))
lower   <- data.frame(x = c(1:2048), y = runif(2048, min = -3, max = 3), blah = runif(2048, min = -0.3, max = 0.6))
quantiles <- c(0.01, 0.05, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95, 0.99)
plot.violin.density.comparison(colname, upper, lower, quantiles)
```